# Ethernet connection is lost after dual-booting W10

Tags: internet, ethernet, connection

I did clean installs of Ubuntu two times hoping it would get my internet connection back. It did. But after I switch back to Windows 10 and switch again to Ubuntu, I can't connect to ethernet. I am using wired connection and can provide any info needed. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: While booting it says netplan is exited. That might be i tried to edit it but i dont think it is the cause.

Comment: i cannot see any connections in nmtui.

Comment: Is fast-boot on? It normally is fine with just Windows, but it is known to cause _tons_ of issues when dual-booting. If it is on, then turn it off

Comment: It is off. It was off too when i was installing ubuntu. After some restarts i managed to get the connection back but not it is lost again. I dont think it is an code issue. Im using a network adapter. That might be the cause but i could not come up with something yet.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinator will do in a bit and post them here. much appreciated if you can help.